# #1054 - Unknown column 'Brisbane' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

Write an SQL statement that uses a sub-query to retrieve all the information about the guests from Brisbane?

```
SELECT * FROM guest
WHERE guestCity = Brisbane IN (SELECT guestCity FROM guest
                               WHERE guestCity = Brisbane)
```

But it kept saying:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'Brisbane' in 'where clause'

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone shed some light please?

```
guestNo, guestName, guestAddress, guestCity, guestState, guestPostcode
1, Bill Watson, 56 Gee Street, Brisbane, QLD, 4000
2, Sharon Stone, 64 New Drive, Sydney, NSW, 2000
3, Mark Harris, 100 Regents Park Road, Brisbane, QLD ,4000
4, Silvia Smith, 312 West Road, Melbourne, VIC, 3000
```

Comment: Your question as written makes little sense.  Why would you need a subquery rather than just using `SELECT * FROM guest WHERE guestCity = 'Brisbane'` ?

Comment: Add table definition(s), sample table data, and also the expected result!

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'Brisbane'`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm just using what my teachers have had given me, I'm following the 'learning guide' while answering the assessments, and that was part of the question. I don't know.

Comment: We can't answer the question since we don't know tables, columns etc...

Comment: @jarlh yeah that make sense. I'll see if i can send the tables and columns here.

Comment: @jarlh I don't know how to send it here or attach a file here. Is there some other way for me to send it?

Comment: Cut-and-paste. Everybody prefer text before images and links.

Comment: @jarlh okay yeah, sorry, I'm new to this website also.

guestNo,  guestName,  guestAddress,  guestCity,  guestState,  guestPostcode, 
1, Bill Watson, 56 Gee Street, Brisbane, QLD, 4000,
2, Sharon Stone, 64 New Drive, Sydney, NSW, 2000,
3, Mark Harris, 100 Regents Park Road, Brisbane, QLD ,4000,
4, Silvia Smith, 312 West Road, Melbourne, VIC, 3000,

Comment: Seems like you have all info in that single table. I can't understand why you're supposed to use a sub-query...

Comment: @jarlh 
Booking Table
bookingID,  guestNo,  roomNo,  dateFrom,  dateTo, 
1, 1, 12, 01-12-2014, 31-12-2014,
2, 2, 20, 01-11-2014, 01-12-2014,
3, 3, 5, 01-01-2015, 31-01-2015,
4, 4, 7, 08-12-2014, 27-12-2014,

Comment: @jarlh Hotel Table

hotelNo  hotelName  hotelAddress  hotelCity  hotelState  hotelPostcode 
1 EagleHilton 1234 Mountain Drive Brisbane QLD 4000
2 EagleSavoy 4321 Valley Hill Sydney NSW 2000
3 EagleMarriott 2143 River Drive Brisbane QLD 4000
4 EagleWindsor 3241 SevenLakes Court Brisbane QLD 4000
5 EagleAstoria 2211 Plum Drive Sydney NSW 2000
6 EagleLotti 4141 Apple Drive Melbourne VIC 3000
7 EagleParkRoyal 3223 Silver Boulevard Melbourne VIC 3000

Comment: @jarlh
roomNo  hotelNo  roomType  roomPrice 
1 1 Single 70.00
2 1 Double 90.00
3 1 Family 110.00
4 2 Single 70.00
5 2 Double 90.00
6 2 Family 110.00
7 3 Single 70.00
8 3 Double 90.00
9 3 Family 110.00
10 4 Single 70.00
11 4 Double 90.00
12 4 Family 110.00
13 3 Single 75.00
14 5 Single 70.00
15 5 Double 90.00
16 5 Family 110
17 6 Single 70
18 6 Double 90
19 6 Family 110
20 7 Single 70
21 7 Double 90
22 7 Family 110
23 1 Single 80
24 2 Single 80
25 2 Single 80
26 3 Single 80
27 3 Single 75

Comment: Can't you edit your question instead? Hard to read columns when there are no line breaks...

Answer (score 1):

Can  you please try this query . It will return list of guest who are having 
guestCity  as **'Brisbane'**

```
SELECT * FROM guest 
WHERE guestCity = 'Brisbane'
```

Comment: I'm not coding I'm just satisfying what my teachers are requiring me to do. They want me to use subquery for that one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the sub query to return what you need.

You also need to wrap strings in single quotes

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM guest g
WHERE g.guestCity = 'Brisbane'
```

Sub Query

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM guest g
WHERE g.guestCity IN (SELECT sg.guestCity 
                      FROM guest sg
                      WHERE sg.guestCity = 'Brisbane')
```

Comment: Okay, but in my assignment, it says I have to use a subquery for that one. If it really doesn't work I'll ask my teachers then.